# Importing a python file that only contains an object

Tags: python

Let's say I want to have a list object like in my list_of_employees.py

```
list = [{'name': "John Doe", 'age': 22, 'employed': True}, {'name': "Mary Doe", 'age': 24, 'employed': False}]
```

and that's all that's in that file.

How do I do it so that my list_of_employees file only really contains the list object, and how do I import it as an object to say, a employee_processing.py file?

Comment: Yes you can use ```from list_of_employees import my_list``` wherever you want use my_list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You import it like this in your module:

```
from list_of_employees import my_list
```

in **list_of_employees.py**, you have `my_list` in the global scope:

```
my_list = [{'name': "John Doe", 'age': 22, 'employed': True}, {'name': "Mary Doe", 'age': 24, 'employed': False}]
import
```

It is better not to shadow the builtin name `list` with variable names.